# Jquery validate multiple input on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to create a jquery function to validate user inputs before submitting the form but it is showing me an error `TypeError: $ival.val(...) is null`, I couldn't see what i am doing wrong. I also don't want to use `jQuery validate library`, I want to create my own simple validation.

**Validation**

```
function checkValidate(input_el){
    var status_check = true;
    var $ival = $(input_el);
        if(($(input_el).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input_el).attr('name') == 'email') && $ival.val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
            status_check = false;
        } else {
            var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
            if($(input_el).attr('type') == 'tel' && (!filter.test($ival.val().trim()) || $(input_el).val().trim() < 8)){
                status_check = false;
            } else {
                if($ival.val().trim() < 1) {
                    status_check = false;
                }
            }
        }   
    return status_check;
}

function setValidation(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();
    $(input).addClass('inputHasError');
}
```

**Post Function**

```
function postBusinessSetup(self, check) {
    if(check) {
        console.log('YES');
    } else {
        console.log('NO');
    }
}
```

**Submit Code**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#ExampleForm', function(e) {
    var inputs = $('.required-data', this);
    var check = true;
    var self = this;
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if(checkValidate(inputs[i]) == false) {
            setValidation(inputs[i]);
            check = false;
        }
    }
    postBusinessSetup(this, check);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Html**

```
<form id="ExampleForm">
    <input type="text" class="required-data"/>
    <input type="email" class="required-data"/>
    <input type="tel" class="required-data"/>
    <input type="url" class="required-data"/>
    <select class="required-data"><option value="hello">hello</option></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the function trim when the input is empty cause the error.

```
$ival.val().trim()
```

You can store it in a variable, you really can also optimize your code

```
var $val = $ival.val() ? $ival.val().trim() : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom validate method, as follows:

```
var tester = '';

$('input').each(function () {

    var value = $(this).attr('value');

    value == '' ? tester += 'Please provide'+$(this).attr('name'): false;
});

if(tester == ''){

        //--------DO YOUR STUFF

    });
}else{
    alert(tester);
}
```